# Continuous maps vs open maps in topological homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, continuity, definition, open-map

My lecturer writes in my topology notes that :

A map $f:(X,\tau)\rightarrow (Y,\tau')$ is a homeomorphism if it is a bijection and both $f,f^{-1}$ are continuous.

However he then goes on to write that :

If $f$ is homeomorphism then $f$ and it's inverse $f^{-1}$ map open sets to  open sets and we call them open maps and that we should note that open maps are not necessarily continuous.

He gives the example :

Let $X=\{a,b\}$, consider $id_x:(X,\text{trivial topology})\rightarrow(X,\text{discrete topology})$

This is a bijection.

It's inverse is continuous

But the map itself is not continuous

$id_x(\{a\})=\{a\}$ is not open in the trivial topology.

I'm having trouble seeing how this is consistent with the definition though, could anyone please help me understand ?

Comment: $id_x$ is a bijection, but it's not continuous, hence it's not a homeomorphism. $id_x^{-1}$ is continuous, meaning inverse image of open set under $id_x^{-1}$ is open, hence $id_x$ maps open sets to open sets, so it's open. $id_x$ maps open sets to non-open sets, hence $id_x$ is not continuous and $id_x^{-1}$ is not open.

Answer (score 1):

Every set is open in discrete topology, so $\{a\}$ is open in $X$ with discrete topology. The inverse image of this set under the identity map is  $\{a\}$ is itself. But the only open sets in trivial topology are the empty set and $X$. Hence (assuming $X$ is not  a singleton)  the inverse image is not open so the identity map is not continuous.

Continuity of the inverse map follows from the fact that every set is open in discrete topology.

Comment: I can see why it's not continuous , I just don't understand how we can still call it homeomorphic given that the definition said we required it to be continuous

Comment: The example is only to show that an open map need not be continuous. It has  nothing  to do with homeomorphisms.

Comment: A map is open if the image of **every** open set is open. A map is continuous if the inverse image of **every** open set is open.

Comment: but my lecturer gave the note I mentioned above which says if $f$ is a  homeomorphism then $f$ and it's inverse $f^{-1}$ map open sets to open sets and we call them open maps and that we should note that open maps are not necessarily continuous. this is the part that confuses me , as to why it's not contrary to the definition?

Comment: Contrary to what definition?

Comment: Your teacher has mixed two facts and a definition in one sentence (which is bad idea). That is what is  causing the confusion. The example is only to illustrate the last part of the sentence and it does not involve any homeomorphism.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ah okay, That is what was causing my confusion indeed, In the way that it was phrased I thought they must be somehow connected, thank you for clarifying